# Unable to login into admin after theme change

Tags: theming, users

I am new to Drupal and to understand the basics I created a new theme in Drupal and enabled it as default. It works fine, however, I am not being able to log in into admin. I reinstalled Drupal and the admin login works fine. When the default theme is enabled it works, but it doesn't work when my custom theme is enabled.

My *.info* file is -

```
name = My First Custom Theme
description = A custom them to understand how Drupal works
core = 7.x

stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css

regions[header] = Header
regions[content] = Content
regions[menu] = Menu
regions[left_sidebar] = Left Side Bar
regions[main_content] = Main Content
regions[footer] = Footer
```

And my *tpl.php* file is -

```
<div id="header">
    <?php print render($page['header']); ?>
</div>

<div id="menu">
    <?php print render($page['menu']); ?>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="left_sidebar">
            <?php print render($page['left_sidebar']); ?>
        </div>

        <div id="main_content">
            <?php print render($page['main_content']); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <?php print render($page['footer']); ?>
</div>
```

I tried accessing admin page using following ways but without success -

> http://www.mysite.com/user
>
> http://www.mysite.com/?q=user

Any idea where I am going wrong ?

Comment: What is the erroryoure getting on that pages ?

Comment: No error. It just reloads and stays on the same page, although the title of the page changes to 'User account'

Comment: Have you moved the content block from the standard Content region to your new Main Content region?

Comment: Sorry @Clive I didn't get you (just started Drupal yesterday), but there isn't any content block in my tpl.php file.

Comment: If you go to admin/structure/blocks is the content block assigned to any region?

Comment: Yes it is assigned to 'Content' region. And I updated my tpl.php code, have added <div id='content'> there

Comment: @Sachyn but the print is $page['main_content'] shouldn't be $page[content] if you assign content region?

Comment: @SumitMadan So you think I need to make change in tpl.php file?

Comment: @Sachyn I think yes...

Comment: @Sachyn, did Sumit Madan's idea work? I am new to Drupal too, but I wonder if it has to do with there being a different theme for the admin pages. What theme is your admin set to? also, is any of your content set up to use the regions defined by the tpl file?

Comment: @Watki02 In my case I was getting error because I didn't include `<?php print render($page['content']); ?>` in my tpl.php file. So the drupal login form wasn't appearing on my site since no default region was specified.

Answer (score 1):

To quote you, it sounds like the answer to your question is you needed to:

> ...include `<?php print render($page['content']); ?>` in my tpl.php file.
>   ...the drupal login form wasn't appearing on my site since no default
>   region was specified.

Comment: ya, that's right

Comment: @Sachyn: not a big fan of writing or marking answers, eh? :)

Answer (score 0):

My whole site crashed due to an error similar to the one above. It’s deadly, because I couldn’t even log into my Admin control panel.
Warning: require_once(/public_html/site/wp-content/themes/flexfit-child/framework/functions/meta-box/meta-box.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/skegley/public_html/site/wp-content/themes/flexfit/functions.php on line 239
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required ‘public_html/site/wp-content/themes/flexfit-child/framework/functions/meta-box/meta-box.php’ (include_path=’.:/opt/php54/lib/php’) in /home2/skegley/public_html/site/wp-content/themes/flexfit/functions.php on line 239

To fix, go into WordPress installation database.

The SQL is:

INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_id`, `option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES

[a bunch of irrelevant lines]

(47, ‘template’, ‘flexfit’, ‘yes’),
(48, ‘stylesheet’, ‘flexfit-child’, ‘yes’),
Change the last line displayed there to
(48, ‘stylesheet’, ‘flexfit’, ‘yes’),

In other words, to fix the broken site, go to wp_options table. installing the child theme as normal only changes stylesheet to the child theme. you have to change the stylesheet back to the original theme’s stylesheet.